# php codeigniter controller not performing action after post

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, redirect

I have  a form that posts a search query to my 'search' controller:

```
<div id="search_box">
<?php echo form_open('search'); ?>
<?php echo form_input('searchvalue', 'search...'); ?>
<?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Search!'); ?>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
</div>
```

In my search controller I have the following code:

```
  public function index()
    {
           $page = 'search';
        $category = 'search';

         if($this->input->post('searchvalue')) {
                  redirect('search/query');
         };


......

}
```

My problem is that it won't do the redirect. I have the form helper autoloaded. What can I do to solve this mystery. Is it a case for the batman?

Comment: It should do the redirect, however, this might not do what you think it does. How do you pass the searchvalue to the new controller for example? Additionally, you should do some get redirect after post, see this CI patch: https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/pull/338

Comment: Why are you defaulting them to an index function of a controller only to redirect them to the query function of the same controller?  Why not just have the search view submit to the query function itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Codeigniter if you ask for a POST variable from the Input class it will return the value or FALSE if the value is empty (Personal Experience) or not found.

So Maybe instead put in a Hidden field with a Dummy value and just check for that on each submit. You can then perform validation and redirect. This will then work if the search query is provided or not.

And the `;` after you `if` is not valid PHP.

For Example:

```
<div id="search_box">
<?php echo form_open('search'); ?>
<?php echo form_hidden('mysearchform', 'true'); ?>
<?php echo form_input('searchvalue', 'search...'); ?>
<?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Search!'); ?>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
</div>

public function index() {

$page = 'search';
$category = 'search';

if($this->input->post('mysearchform') != FALSE) {

    // Remember to Validate your Query

    redirect('search/query');
}

}
```

**Hope I understood that correctly.**

Comment: Tried the above code and it still doesn't work, hmmm... it should work.... any ideas???

Comment: Maybe try <?php echo form_open('search/index'); ?> otherwise I'm a bit stumped.

Comment: And be sure to check using something like Chrome's Web Developer Tools to see where and what is actually being submitted.

Comment: Found the issue. For some reason, haven't worked out why yet, my htaccess file was blocking forms posting. A thorough investigation will follow..